# Spree 3.0 how to add a footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

With spree3.0 there is no footer by default. All themes are outdated with this version. How can one add footer with latest version of spree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add a footer by using the following deface override:

```
Deface::Override.new(virtual_path:     "spree/layouts/spree_application",
                 insert_after:     "body",
                 name:             "footer",
                 partial:          "spree/shared/footer")
```

If you haven't already you will need to create the file structure in views > spree > shared. This is where you will add your _footer.html.erb partial file

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new file at `app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb` and copy the content from the [original](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb) then put your own footer and whatever you want in there.

The benefits of doing this over using deface is you have more control and it's a lot simpler. The downside is it's harder to update spree to newer versions if the layout gets changed (but not a whole lot will change in there anyway).